# Cypress intercept with not condition

Tags: cypress

I have the following service calls on click of an element. I will need to intercept a request that does not have `f0000000000` in the endpoint.

```
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f0000000000/path1 - GET
https://example.com/f2021090606/path1 - GET
```

How can we achieve this in cypress? Do we have any similar options?

```
 cy.intercept("GET", "**/NOT(f0000000000)/path1*").as('getForecast');
 cy.get('#some').click();
 cy.wait('@getForecast').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With regex

You wrap the part to exclude in a negative lookahead group,

```js
(?!NOT-THE-TEXT-YOU-ARE-LOOKING-FOR)
```

but also **must add wildcard for any other text in that place** after the group, i.e `.*`

```js
((?!NOT-THE-TEXT-YOU-ARE-LOOKING-FOR).*)
```

**Shortest**

- Ensure any domain, but must have `/path1` and not have `f0000000000`

  ```js
  const regex = /((?!f0000000000).*)\/path1/
  cy.intercept(regex, {}).as('intercept')
  cy.wait('@intercept')
  ```

**More exact**

- Specify the domain more exactly

  ```js
  cy.intercept(/^https:\/\/example\.com\/((?!f0000000000).*)\/path1/, {}).as('intercept')
  cy.wait('@intercept')
  ```

- Specify digits more exactly

  If you **always** have `f` prefix and just want the digits wilcarded, move the `f` outside the exclusion.

  Optionally replace `.*` with `[0-9]{10}` to specify exactly 10 digits not matching `0000000000`

  ```js
  cy.intercept(/^https:\/\/example\.com\/f((?!0000000000)[0-9]*)\/path1/, {}).as('intercept')
  cy.wait('@intercept')
  ```

---

#### With minimatch

Just change `NOT(f0000000000)` to `!(f0000000000)`

```js
const url1 = 'https://example.com/f2021090606/path1x'
const match1 = Cypress.minimatch(url1, '**/!(f0000000000)/path1*')
expect(match1).to.eq(true)
```

Conversly

```js
const url2 = 'https://example.com/f0000000000/path1x'
const match2 = Cypress.minimatch(url2, '**/!(f0000000000)/path1*')
expect(match2).to.eq(false)
```

Intercept

```js
cy.intercept('**/!(f0000000000)/path1*', {}).as('intercept')

//or

cy.intercept('**/f!(0000000000)/path1*', {}).as('intercept')
```

But be careful with trailing path parts

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/f0000000001/path1/x'
const match = Cypress.minimatch(url, '**/!(f0000000000)/path1/*')
expect(match).to.eq(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex for this:

```js
cy.intercept(/^(?!.*f0000000000\/path1).*$/gm).as('getForecast')
```

This will intercept the url which doesn't have `f0000000000`. This is a very basic regex, you can always enhance it as per your needs.

[image: regex screenshot]

You can also look into the [Intercept Cypress Recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__intercept/cypress/integration/matching-spec.js).